# Complicated Double Text Underline

Tags: css, border

So I'm looking to create an effect where a header font is underlined. I want the underline to stretch the width of the div that the header is in. BUT I want the area of that underline that is directly underneath the text to be in a separate color. So under the text it should be blue, but the moment that underline is no longer underneath the text, it should be grey. I was figuring a double border system would work, but I'm not sure if it's even possible anymore to do this with just CSS...is it?

Comment: I would have to be Sherlock Holmes to interpret this can you provide an image

Comment: From the understanding that I got, you could do two divs. One for the header text, with a `border-bottom` of blue, then a div floating to the right of it with full width, with a `border-bottom` of grey. But again, I could be wrong since I have no picture to go off of.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another quick solution. Change the 500px to anything you want, could be a percentage.

HTML

```
<div class="blue">
    Header
</div>
<div class="grey">
    &nbsp;
</div>
<div class="clear">
</div>
```

CSS

```
.blue {
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid blue;
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 0;
}

.grey {
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid grey;
    float: left;
    width: 500px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    z-index:-1;
}

.clear {
    clear: both;
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/UuYvv/

Comment: I should have been a little more specific...check out this picture:

Comment: http://www.dualdigitaldesign.com/underline.jpg     Right there under "Events" is what I'm going for. And this is a Wordpress template I'm editing (and a responsive one at that), so putting extra divs around the h3 tag here is a last resort, cause it's not gonna be easy.

Answer (score 0):

Did this with fixed positioning [here](http://jsfiddle.net/D46BB/). If you try and do it with everything relative, it gets a little funkier but still sort of works. Hope that helps!

html:

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="word">My Word</div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.outer {
left: 0px;
top: 0px;
height: 20px;
width: 200px;
border-bottom: 2px solid grey;
overflow: visible;
position:fixed;
}
.word {
position: fixed;
top: 0px;
width: 80px;
margin-bottom: -1px;
border-bottom: 2px solid blue;
}
```

Comment: Alternatively you could have them beside each other and just float them both left, with the grey one full width and the blue one only the width of the text. +1 to you for this though.

Comment: Yeah i just noticed that without fixed or absolute position, the borders acted strange. One would somehow get double the size of the other. didn't try floating in particular though.